# I need to configure my webserver that can be used like shopiy.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, reverse-dns

I need to configure my webserver that can be used like shopiy.com. I will create sub domains dynamically with php while creating user accounts. The users should be able to point the account with their own domain name.

I am using AWS for my hosting and created Elastic IP to make the IP static one.

Registered my main domain name with GoDaddy and pointed to AWS with this elastic IP address.

**I will explain the details with an example here.**

I have a web application which accepts user registration hosted with a domain name say www.abc.com. When a user creates an account, he will get his own url like hisname.abc.com, which I have accomplished through my web application itself. Now my question is if the above user purchases his own domain name www.hisname.com, he would be able to point the name to hisname.abc.com. What configuration should I make in my server to accept these requests as we are expecting a lot of users could do the above process.

Comment: As a general answer, you can simply accept any domain name in web server configuration. (since this is a trivial answer, I assume there might be something else to your question, but I couldn't figure out what :)

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002251/aws-multiple-domains-pointing-to-same-server/35002805#35002805

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I a beginner with DNS. I need more specific on this.

Comment: If you are expecting a lot of users, consider the fact that you can't effectively scale with a single EIP.  You are trying to accomplish a task that is not something a "beginner with DNS" should be attempting -- there are many mistakes and sub-optimal decisions that you can make which will cause you to experience service disruptions and cause hassles for your customers when they are all required to later change their settings.  Understanding the complexities of all that is involved to make such a solution viable requires expertise substantially beyond what can be conveyed in the Q&A format.